# FrontBoardServices - [FBSSceneParameters initWithSpecification:]: Crash using CarPlay

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, carplay

In an app which support CarPlay (pre iOS 14, using MPPlayableContentManager and MPNowPlayingInfoCenter) I'm getting crash when I touch the app on the head unit. Based on the searches I made similar issue happened earlier but I didn't find any solution for that.

Similar issue to the one I am having: [Why Does CarPlay Crash In Real Car?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339572/why-does-carplay-crash-in-real-car)

Based on searches I made users found it also annoying that the were not able to use CarPlay apps for days.

Is there any fix or workaround for this?

Logs:

```
FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSceneParameters initWithSpecification:]:
    0x7fff25a2e81e <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff25a2e81f <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff25a2e822 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
    0x7fff25a2e824 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
    0x7fff25a2e826 <+8>:   pushq  %r12
    0x7fff25a2e828 <+10>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff25a2e829 <+11>:  subq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x7fff25a2e82d <+15>:  movq   %rdx, %r15
    0x7fff25a2e830 <+18>:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
    0x7fff25a2e833 <+21>:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e836 <+24>:  callq  *0x5f75142c(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff20191840: objc_retain
    0x7fff25a2e83c <+30>:  movq   %rax, %r14
    0x7fff25a2e83f <+33>:  leaq   0x5f75502a(%rip), %rdi    ; @"FBSSceneSpecification"
    0x7fff25a2e846 <+40>:  callq  0x7fff25a79e2a            ; symbol stub for: NSClassFromString
    0x7fff25a2e84b <+45>:  testq  %r14, %r14
    0x7fff25a2e84e <+48>:  je     0x7fff25a2e903            ; <+229>
    0x7fff25a2e854 <+54>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e857 <+57>:  movq   %rax, %rsi
    0x7fff25a2e85a <+60>:  callq  0x7fff25a79f98            ; symbol stub for: objc_opt_isKindOfClass
    0x7fff25a2e85f <+65>:  testb  $0x1, %al
    0x7fff25a2e861 <+67>:  je     0x7fff25a2e909            ; <+235>
    0x7fff25a2e867 <+73>:  leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e86b <+77>:  movq   %rbx, (%rdi)
    0x7fff25a2e86e <+80>:  movq   0x5aaae8b3(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff804ded98: FBSSceneParameters
    0x7fff25a2e875 <+87>:  movq   %rax, 0x8(%rdi)
    0x7fff25a2e879 <+91>:  movq   0x5aaac058(%rip), %rsi    ; "init"
    0x7fff25a2e880 <+98>:  callq  0x7fff25a79f86            ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSendSuper2
    0x7fff25a2e885 <+103>: movq   %rax, %rbx
    0x7fff25a2e888 <+106>: testq  %rax, %rax
    0x7fff25a2e88b <+109>: je     0x7fff25a2e8ea            ; <+204>
    0x7fff25a2e88d <+111>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e890 <+114>: addq   $0x18, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e894 <+118>: movq   %r15, %rsi
    0x7fff25a2e897 <+121>: callq  0x7fff25a79fc8            ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
    0x7fff25a2e89c <+126>: movq   0x5aaac675(%rip), %rsi    ; "settingsClass"
    0x7fff25a2e8a3 <+133>: movq   0x5f7513ae(%rip), %r15    ; (void *)0x00007fff20175280: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff25a2e8aa <+140>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8ad <+143>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff25a2e8b0 <+146>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8b3 <+149>: callq  0x7fff25a79f3e            ; symbol stub for: objc_alloc_init
    0x7fff25a2e8b8 <+154>: movq   0x8(%rbx), %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8bc <+158>: movq   %rax, 0x8(%rbx)
    0x7fff25a2e8c0 <+162>: movq   0x5f751399(%rip), %r12    ; (void *)0x00007fff20191530: objc_release
    0x7fff25a2e8c7 <+169>: callq  *%r12
    0x7fff25a2e8ca <+172>: movq   0x5aaac64f(%rip), %rsi    ; "clientSettingsClass"
    0x7fff25a2e8d1 <+179>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8d4 <+182>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff25a2e8d7 <+185>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8da <+188>: callq  0x7fff25a79f3e            ; symbol stub for: objc_alloc_init
    0x7fff25a2e8df <+193>: movq   0x10(%rbx), %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8e3 <+197>: movq   %rax, 0x10(%rbx)
    0x7fff25a2e8e7 <+201>: callq  *%r12
    0x7fff25a2e8ea <+204>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff25a2e8ed <+207>: callq  *0x5f75136d(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff20191530: objc_release
    0x7fff25a2e8f3 <+213>: movq   %rbx, %rax
    0x7fff25a2e8f6 <+216>: addq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x7fff25a2e8fa <+220>: popq   %rbx
    0x7fff25a2e8fb <+221>: popq   %r12
    0x7fff25a2e8fd <+223>: popq   %r14
    0x7fff25a2e8ff <+225>: popq   %r15
    0x7fff25a2e901 <+227>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff25a2e902 <+228>: retq   
    0x7fff25a2e903 <+229>: int3   
->  0x7fff25a2e904 <+230>: jmp    0x7fff25a2e854            ; <+54>
    0x7fff25a2e909 <+235>: int3   
    0x7fff25a2e90a <+236>: jmp    0x7fff25a2e867            ; <+73>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you added both entitlements to your .entitlements file? We had the issue that we received both entitlements (`com.apple.developer.carplay-audio` and `com.apple.developer.playable-content`) and added them both even though we haven't implemented the new CarPlay yet (using the CarPlay framework and SceneDelegates and stuff). In that case, the app crashes on iOS 14+.

Comment: Yes, issue was solved by clearing out CarPlay from the entitlements! Thanks!

Comment: Could you accept the answer so others can see that this is a solution?